# Ignorar evento click de etiqueta padre

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tengo una tabla de datos hecha en Angular con TypeScript del siguiente estilo:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|          | ID         | Nombre     | Apellido   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| [Button] | 00001      | Nom        | Ape        |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Formada por el siguiente código:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th> </th>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> Nombre </th>
    <th> Apellido </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr (click)="ComprobarCustomer(customer.id)" *ngFor="let customer of customerList">
      <td> 
        <button click="checkCustomer()"> 
          <fa-icon ... ></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td> {{customer.id}} </td>
      <td> {{customer.name}} </td>
      <td> {{customer.lastName}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito que el botón no accione el evento click que contiene la etiqueta `<tr>` de alguna forma **que no implique quitar el evento de la línea y ponerlo en cada una de las celdas.**

Comment: Esto puede servirte https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En angular puedes acceder al evento con la variable `$event`.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr
      (click)="ComprobarCustomer(customer.id)"
      *ngFor="let customer of customerList"
    >
      <td>
        <button
          (click)="checkCustomer($event, customer)"
          class="btn btn-outline-dark"
        >
          fa-icon
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

En tu `component.ts` detienes la propagación del evento.

```javascript
 ComprobarCustomer(id: string) {
    console.log('Comprobar customer id:', id);
  }

  checkCustomer(event, customer) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log({ customer });
  }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mhwbop?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Era justo lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias.